# Aromaticity in resonance stabilisation

Tags: organic-chemistry

In this question;

[image]

(2) is, apparently, the correct answer, as it has the most resonating structures.
In comparing resonance- structure stability, shouldn't you also check whether it destabilizes the species by making it anti-aromatic?

For example, in option (1), resonance into the left ring would result in it having 8π-electrons, making it anti-aromatic.

Is this not considered because it's just a resonance hybrid, and Hückel's rule isn't considered for hybrids?

Comment: Of course you need to consider it. "most resonating structures" is largely irrelevant. (2) has both rings aromatic, that's the reason.

Comment: So (2) isn't it?

Comment: Yes! as @Mithoron explained.